# Dominated convergence for integral equal to 0

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a (Borel) measurable function such that
$$\int_{[0,\theta]} g(t)t^{n-1}\lambda(\textrm{d} t) = 0,$$
for all $\theta \in (0, \infty)$.

In the solution it is now mentioned that Lebesgue's theorem of dominated convergence yields that
$$\int_{[0,\infty)} g(t)t^{n-1}\lambda(\textrm{d}t) = 0$$

and therefore the integrals of positive and negative part (over $[0, \infty)$) are the same value and exist (are finite).

I'm not able to find the integrable majorant in order to show that Lebesgue's theorem can be applied in this case (to provide the argument for the existence and equality of the integral). How is it possible to do so?

Comment: You cannot use DCT here unless there is some additional hypothesis.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Which argument would be necessary to guarantee this result or can another theorem be used to prove that the domain of integration can be extended in the way it has been suggested?

Comment: @PeterMcCoy: As Kavi said, more conditions on $g$ are required. One could be that $g(t)t^{n-1}$ is integrable in $[0,\infty)$. Both then thing are very simple.